# Python f-string and append()

Tags: python

I hope y'all doing fine!

So I want to make 5 groups of 6 people randomly chosen from a list and then append those 6 chosen names to the special group.
Example: If a, b, c, d, e, f, are the first six chosen names -> append those names to group1;
after the group1 contains 6 names, then the next 6 names -> append to group2; and so and so till I have 5 groups of 6 people.

I hope you understand me and that you can help :)

My code:

```py
import random

names = [30 names i dont wanna share]

group1 = list()
group2 = list()
group3 = list()
group4 = list()
group5 = list()


def choosegroup():


    def chooserandom():
        return(random.choice(names))


    def creategroup():
        for i in range(1,7):

            chosed = chooserandom()
            names.remove(chosed)

            #while(chosed in group1):
                #print('Ups')
                #print(chosed + ' already chosed')
            #    chosed = chooserandom()


            #print(chosed)

            group1.append(chosed)

    #print('Group 1:' + '\n' + str(group1) + '\n')

    createdgroup = creategroup()

    print(group1)

for i in range(1,6):
    print(f'Group {i}')
    choosegroup()
    group1.clear()
```

Comment: I tried to use f-string like f(group{i}).append(chosed) so when its the first loop it adds to group1, then to group2 and so and so, but that didn't work!

Comment: If you are able to install new packages, [`more_itertools`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.chunked) has some great utilities for things like this.

Comment: If you start to add number suffixes to your variable names it is a sign, that you should use an appropriate data structure for those variables.

Answer (score 2):

```
random.shuffle(names)
groups = [ names[i:i+6] for i in range(0, len(names), 6) ]
```

Now `groups[0]`, `groups[1]` etc. are your 6-person groups.

Comment: Aight, thank you for your help, imma try this in a bit and ill let you know if this was it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Once you have your list of names, to split them into random groups, I would instead use `numpy`

```
import numpy as np
groups = np.array(names)
np.shuffle(groups)
groups = np.reshape(groups, (5,6))
```

As an example with numbers instead of names

```
>>> names = np.arange(30)
>>> names
array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16,
       17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29])
>>> np.random.shuffle(names)
>>> names
array([ 8, 18, 23,  7, 25, 14, 11, 20, 13, 24, 15, 26, 19, 21, 12, 17,  0,
        6,  3, 10, 29,  9, 16, 28, 22,  5,  1,  4, 27,  2])
>>> np.reshape(names, (5,6))
array([[ 8, 18, 23,  7, 25, 14],
       [11, 20, 13, 24, 15, 26],
       [19, 21, 12, 17,  0,  6],
       [ 3, 10, 29,  9, 16, 28],
       [22,  5,  1,  4, 27,  2]])
```

Comment: Thank you, but I'm actualy trying to append them to the already defined variables!
Anyways this comes in handy, thanks.

Comment: @PanicKk In general I would avoid making N variables when you could make 1 container of length N. What if you had 1000 groups, would you want to type manually `group1`, `group2`, .... `group1000`? You should consider a list of lists, a 2D array, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can access them from globals as such:

```
globals()[f"group{i}"]
```

though storing and retrieving them from a dictionary is preferable.

You can rewrite your code as follows:

```
import random
from collections import defaultdict

names = [30 names i dont wanna share]
groups = defaultdict(list)

def choosegroup(group_name):


    def chooserandom():
        return(random.choice(names))


    def creategroup(group_name):
        for i in range(1,7):

            chosed = chooserandom()
            names.remove(chosed)

            groups[group_name].append(chosed)

    createdgroup = creategroup()

    print(group_name, "\n", group[group_name])

for i in range(1,6):
    print(f'Group {i}')
    group_name = f"group{i}"
    choosegroup(group_name)
    groups[group_name].clear()
```

Comment: Thanks, this works fine, but i actualy had the code that already does something like this but why i need to do it like append the names in the next variable like:
group1 = ['a', 'b']
group2 = ['c', 'd']
group3 = ['e', 'f']
group4 = ['g', 'h']
group5 = ['i', 'j']

Is because I have to chose 2 strict names in each group and then add 4 more randomly from the list.

Comment: Yes and now you can append to any of those groups simply with the name as such

`group[group_name].append()` or `group[f"group{i}"].append()`

Comment: Uhm, could you do that for me? Like add that to the code, cuz I dont really get it. Im still learning as you can see, xd

Comment: It's already in the code.  Your for loop now at the bottom creates each list, and appends a random name to each group.  All of these groups exist in the `groups`  dictionary.  You can `print(groups)` to see them all, though your `groups[group_name].clear() at the end clears the lists, making them empty.  Not sure the purpose of that line.

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked, I changed a few lines:
```py
groups = ({'Group 1': ['a', 'b'], 
            'Group 2': ['c,' 'd'], 
            'Group 3': ['e', 'f'], 
            'Group 4': ['g', 'h'], 
            'Group 5': ['i', 'j']})
And this works as I wanted, Thank you again

Comment: My pleasure, mind selecting it as the accepted answer?